# Virtual machine and kernel communication using netlink

Tags: virtual-machine, emulation, netlink

I wrote a linux kernel module and a user space application. They had been communicating very well via netlink. But I got errno 111 (connection refused) when I was trying to run the user space application on an emulated node in CORE (Common Open Research Emulator). Could you help me find the cause (according to CORE, an emulated node is a virtual machine, which uses the same kernel as the local host)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why I got "connection refused" error is because the user-land and kernel-land  processes were not residing in the same network space. The kernel-land process was listening in the "root" space, while the user-land process was sending in another space.

CORE uses Linux virtualization. It creates separate process and network spaces for each emulated node. If an application is running on a CORE node, its user-land process has its own process-ID space and network stack space. The messages sent by the application were confined within the CORE node's own spaces.

To enable kernel-land and user-land communication when CORE is used, we should let the application switch to the kernel's network space first, and then create a netlink socket and send messages over the socket.

To switch to the kernel's network space, we need first mount `/proc` to `/proc_root`. And then, in the application, add `{fd = open("/proc_root/1/ns/net", O_RDONLY); setns(fd, 0);}` before sending messages to the kernel-land process using Netlink.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it happened because of lack of linux capabilities (CAP_NET_ADMIN). Did you check capabilities of your user space process and your VM process?

Comment: Hi Galka, Thanks for answering my question. I posted it about a year ago and now I have found a solution. The problem was that I used Netlink, which only supports kernel and user space communications when the two communicating processes locate in the same network and process spaces. Because a CORE node uses separate network and process spaces, I got an error. I tried to let the CORE node switch to the kernel spaces and then the error was gone. :)

Comment: Hi, Tina. Why didn't you submit the answer, everybody was curious :)

Comment: Well, I didn't know that. Next time I will do :)

Comment: @Tina Do it this time, too, please! This is a Q/A repository, if you can solve a problem, please do post an answer, whether it is your own question or not.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I have posted a more detailed answer!